# How to pass parameters through the associations chain in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

By default, FactoryGirl calls the factories of associations to create them. I can pass a association for a factory as a parameter. But how can I passa an object which should be used deep in the associations chain?

For example:

I have a Post, which has  a PostsManager,  which has an Account, which belongs to the current_user.

When I do a `Factory(:post)` it creates an PostsManager, which creates an Account, which doesn't belongs to the (stubed) current_user.

So, in specs that use the Post factory I have to do:

```
account = Factory(:account, user: current_user)
post_manager = Factory(:post_manager, account: account)
post = Factory(:post, post_manager: post_manager)
```

What I would like to do is call the factory  with `Factory(:post, user: current_user)`, and then pass `current_user` all the way through the associations to the Account factory. Is there a way to do it so?

Comment: Would you add code example.

Comment: Read http://sscce.org please. Without more information we're not able to give you accurate answers.

Comment: He's asking if attributes can be passed down through associations if they don't exist on the original models. This can be done with transient attributes. I have an answer if you will re-open the question.

Comment: made some changes. Hope you can understand it now

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not sure what version of FactoryGirl you are using, but if you are on any recent version (2.6+) you can use Transient Attributes (read more on their ["Getting Started" page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/2.6.x/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes)). You could do something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :post do
    ignore do
      user nil
    end
    posts_manager { FactoryGirl.build(:posts_manager, :user => user) }
  end

  factory :posts_manager do
    ignore do
      user nil
    end
    account { FactoryGirl.build(:account, :user => user) }
  end

  factory :account do
    user { user }
  end

end

FactoryGirl.create(:post, :user => current_user)
```

Comment: I wish I had found this 2 years ago.

Comment: For recent versions of FactoryGirl, use `transient` instead of `ignore`